# Creating an advanced HUD

Tags: wpf, hud

I'm making an interface for the AR Drone Quadcopter in WPF.

I neen some stuff on my HUD to make it usable.

One of the more advanced controls on the HUD is the artificial horizon, which tells the pilot the craft's current alignment to the horizon.

I have these 3 PNGs

[image: The background]

[image: outliner 1]

[image: outliner 3]

The first image I will move (The current pitch of the craft) and rotate (The current roll of the craft).

I will put the second image over the first, this one will only rotate around the center axis, it has ticks at certain degrees which will visualize the craft's roll even more.

The last one I will put on top of the second, this image just a visual improver.

Then I want to mask first image so that you only see whats inside the circle in image 2.

Last but not least I want to add a textblock to it and display the current altitude

The result will look something like this

[image: Result]

I know how to rotate and move the image, but how do I place the images on top of each other, and how do I mask the first image?

edit: Thanks to Ben I've gotten this far:

[image: Rotate no translate]

But I also need to translate the image Y position (The pitch of the aircraft)

[image: With translate]

When I add the translate transform I also translate the Clip (Mask) how can I translate the image without moving the mask?

Comment: you mind sharing the code? :) thanks!

Comment: Its basicly the code you see in my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little sample that how you can use `DrawingGroups` and a `ClipGeometry` inside it.

```
<Grid>
  <Image Source="Images\Background.jpg" />

  <Image>
    <Image.Source>
      <DrawingImage>
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
          <DrawingGroup>
            <DrawingGroup>
              <!-- You can rotate a DrawingGroup -->
              <DrawingGroup.Transform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-15" CenterX="50" CenterY="50" />
              </DrawingGroup.Transform>

              <ImageDrawing ImageSource="Images\last.png" Rect="0,0,100,100" />
              <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                <EllipseGeometry Center="50,50" RadiusX="25" RadiusY="25" />
              </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
            </DrawingGroup>

            <DrawingGroup>
              <ImageDrawing ImageSource="Images\middle.png" Rect="0,0,100,100" />
              <ImageDrawing ImageSource="Images\outer.png" Rect="0,0,100,100" />
            </DrawingGroup>
          </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
      </DrawingImage>
    </Image.Source>
  </Image>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Cool, so last.png is the first image at layer 0, the one that I will rotate? Looks like the entire thing will rotate with that code? Will have to try it out later tonight.. thanks!

Comment: Yes, in that DrawingGroup there are only one image('last.png'). We apply a clipping geometry(a circle in this case) and a transorm on this group. Then we render the two other image on top of this group. (You can remove the DrawingGroup that contains the two image if you want.) And i suggest that you should use a binding on the RotateTransorm's Angle.

Comment: Yeah, I see it now. I missed that it was in a seperate group.. Will try this tonight if i find time and get back to you.. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Works great right away, gotta love WPF :D But one problem.. I also need to translate the BG.. But then i also translate the mask, anyway of solving that?

Comment: Sorry, but i don't really understand.

Answer (score 1):

I was tired last night :D
To get the background to rotate and translate but not the Clipping was just to put the background in a sub group to the clipping group... Now it works!

```
    <Image Width="240" Height="240">
        <Image.Source>
            <DrawingImage>
                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup>
                                <DrawingGroup.Transform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-15" CenterX="120" CenterY="120" />
                                        <TranslateTransform Y="-20" />
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </DrawingGroup.Transform>

                                <ImageDrawing ImageSource="Images\pNxVK.png" Rect="0,0,240,240" />
                            </DrawingGroup>

                            <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                                <EllipseGeometry Center="120,120" RadiusX="60" RadiusY="60">
                                </EllipseGeometry>
                            </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                        </DrawingGroup>

                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <ImageDrawing ImageSource="Images\zUr8D.png" Rect="0,0,240,240" />
                            <ImageDrawing ImageSource="Images\XPZW9.png" Rect="0,0,240,240" />
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>
```